# Powermock or PowerMockito with JUnit 5

Tags: mockito, powermock, junit5, powermockito, junit5-extension-model

Is somebody able to direct me to one solid piece of documentation that outlines how to integrate JUnit 5 with Powermock framework, specifically the PowerMockito class?

I see many people having issue with this on stack overflow and multiple other forums and as of yet I have not seen one solid answer to this problem.

Does this integration even exist? To use Powermock will I need to import JUnit4 vintage maven dependency and essentially have a combination of JUnit4 and 5 dependencies? And if i do this then should i run tests as JUnit4 or Junit5?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/929?

Comment: Hi Progman. Hmm i have not. I will give it a read and see if anything there works. If i find a solution i would post as a full answer.